# php do not understand 元 (CNY) symbol to replace

Tags: php, apache, utf-8, currency

I have the following code, that normalizing file-name on server:

```
private static function normalize($name,$currency) {
    $currencies = array('$', '元', '€');
    preg_match("/([\S]+)(\.\w+(?=$))/", $name, $matches);
    VarDumper::dump($matches); echo '<br>';
    $name = strtolower($matches[1]);
    $ext = strtolower($matches[2]);
    $name = str_replace($currencies, '-' . $currency . '-', $name);
    VarDumper::dump($name); echo '<br>';
    $name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\-\d]+/", "-", $name);
    $name = preg_replace("/\-+/", "-", $name);
    $name = strtolower($name);
    $name = trim($name, ' ,-');
    $name = $name . $ext;

    return $name;
}
```

First dump show following string:

> 1988-1-oz-Gold-Chinese-Panda-100hEG-Bullion-Coin-.999-24K-rev

And second dump shows this:

> 1988-1-oz-gold-chinese-panda-100heg-bullion-coin-.999-24k-rev

On localhost all work fine and CNY char showing correctly, but on dev server string looks like above.

http server: Apache 2.2, AddDefaultCharset utf-8 in httpd.conf enabled.

Can someone advice with possible solution of this problem?

Comment: Have you checked the difference between localhost and dev server enviroment? If taken from db maybe those are db differences

Comment: Yep, ISPmanager screened UTF8 characters, we decided to manually re-upload images with correct names.